# How can I use WHILE loop to get as many sets of data into a table as are available?

Tags: php, javascript

When we run a query in ssms, we can get one or more rows of data per associateID.

However, on a table data,

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>...</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

We believe that the solution to our problem is to loop the data and dump contents in a table.

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Here is the code I am trying to loop:

```
<?php
 //I need the loop here.
 <table>
    <tr>            
     <td class="dataItem" id="SignCode"></td>
     <td class="dataItem" id="SignType"></td>
     <td class="dataItem" id="SignSize"></td>
     <td class="dataItem" id="SignColor"></td>
     <td class="dataItem" id="Facing"></td>
     <td class="dataItem" id="HorizClear"></td>
     <td class="dataItem" id="VertClear"></td>
     <td class="dataItem" id="Angle"></td>
     <td class="dataItem" id="ReflCoat"></td>
     <td class="dataItem" id="Condition"></td>
     <td class="dataItem" id="Status"></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
?>
```

The data is a combination of query and the Javascript array. The query is

```
$tsql="select * from mytable where associateId='$aid'";
```

Then all the form ids are in Javascript like this example:

```
dojo.byId("SignType").innerHTML = obj["SignType"];
```

Comment: how is the set data available to you ?

Comment: http://php.net/while look at example one ;)

Comment: You're likely going to want to loop on the TR or TD, and put the table tags outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The code should look something like this:
(It is still unclear how you acquire the data from the DB.)

```
<?php
$resultSet = ...   // <-- somehow aquire a result-set you can loop through
?>
<table>
    <?php while ($row = <somehow_get_next_row_from_$resultSet_as_associative_array>) {?>
    <tr>
        <td class="dataItem" id="SignCode"><?php echo($row["signCode"]); ?></td>
        <td class="dataItem" id="SignSize"><?php echo($row["signSize"]); ?></td>
        <td class="dataItem" id="SignColor"><?php echo($row["signColor"]); ?></td>
        ...
        <td class="dataItem" id="Status"><?php echo($row["status"]); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

In case the value for `id` (e.g. "SignCode" etc) is the same as the name of the DB column-name AND the query returns the columns in the order you want the HTML-table columns to be, then the part between `<tr>` and `</tr>` could be further simplified as:

```
    ...
    <tr>
    <?php forEach ($row as $key => $value) {?>
        <td class="dataItem" id="<?php echo($key); ?>"><?php echo($value); ?></td>
    <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    ...
```

Comment: Problem is php is on a separate page from the page that contains the html. and you asked an excellent question @George. The data is a combination of query and the javascript array.

The query is `$tsql="select * from mytable where associateId='$aid'";`

Then all the form ids are in javascript like this example:

`dojo.byId("SignType").innerHTML = obj["SignType"];`

Comment: I still don't get what you are trying to do. You have some data retrieved from a DB on the server side and then you want to pass it to client side to process it with JS ? Are you using AJAX ?

Answer (score 0):

If you show us your php code we can give you a better answer but your code should be somthing like this:

```
 <table>
 <?php
    // Your loop
    while($row = /*fetchData()*/) {
 ?>
    <tr>            
     <td class="dataItem" id="SignCode"><?php echo $row['SignCode']; ?></td>
     <td class="dataItem" id="SignType"><?php echo $row['SignType']; ?></td>
     <td class="dataItem" id="SignSize"><?php echo $row['SignSize']; ?></td>
     <td class="dataItem" id="SignColor"><?php echo $row['SignColor']; ?></td>
     <td class="dataItem" id="Facing"><?php echo $row['Facing']; ?></td>
     <td class="dataItem" id="HorizClear"><?php echo $row['HorizClear']; ?></td>
     <td class="dataItem" id="VertClear"><?php echo $row['VertClear']; ?></td>
     <td class="dataItem" id="Angle"><?php echo $row['Angle']; ?></td>
     <td class="dataItem" id="ReflCoat"><?php echo $row['ReflCoat']; ?></td>
     <td class="dataItem" id="Condition"><?php echo $row['Condition']; ?></td>
     <td class="dataItem" id="Status"><?php echo $row['Status']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```